# Can anyone help me identify this angular Japanese font? (Katakana & hiragana samples)

Tags: font-identification, japanese

Here's a cleaned up version: 「ぷちゃへんざレディオ」
[image: ぷちゃへんざ][image: レディオ]

And the original (From My Hero Academia vol. 4 back cover):
[image: full]

It's quite distinctive, so I hope someone can help. The other font that can be seen in the image (reading Present Mic) I've identified as Blippo Black, so it seems likely the other lettering is also done in a readily available font. I've had no luck browsing Japanese font sites, and en.likefont.com didn't seem to have it in their database. Even suggestions for other font identification services with Japanese support are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The question have all the required information... why is it still ON HOLD?

Comment: @PepeOchoa Because reopening isn't automatic. We mods are only five and all volunteers, so reopening gets relegated to a review queue that users with a certain level of reputation can review. That takes some time. Please bear with the system :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified version of [F1-ブロックライン](http://imagenavi.jp/font/detail.aspx?bid=2847) (available from this link), a font included in a typographers' compilation package [FONT1000](http://www.font1000.com/).

[image]